# gitignore not untracking my database

Tags: git, mongodb, github

I set up a simple nodejs express server with a mongodb database.
Unfortunately I forgot to add a proper gitignore before trying to sync my code to github.

The push command fails, because the journals of my database are too huge.

Now I've added a .gitignore file that contains just the line

```
data
```

since that's where the database is stored.

I ran this code in the shell (Ubuntu 14.10):

```
git rm -r --cached
git add .
git commit -m "untracked database"
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Surprisingly the push still fails:

> file data/journal/j._0 is 1024mb; this exceeds githubs file size limit of 100mb

So the gitignore is not working ?

```
git rm -r --cached
git add .gitignore
git add *
git commit -m "untracked database 2"
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Same error

```
git rm -r --cached data/
```

> fatal: pathspec 'data/' did not match any files

```
git rm -r data/
```

> fatal: pathspec 'data/' did not match any files

```
git rm -r --cached data/**
```

> fatal: pathspec 'data/journal/' did not match any files

To me it seems like these files are not tracked by git. Why is it trying to sync them ?

**UPDATE:**

I changed the content of my .gitignore to

```
data/
```

same problem.
Then I tried

```
data/**
```

the error persists.

```
cat .gitignore
   data/
git rm -r --cached
git add .
git add *
   The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
   data
   Use -f if you really want to add them.
   fatal: no files added
git commit -m "untracked data"
    On branch master
    nothing to commit, working directory clean
ls
    app.js      app.ts  data/         node_modules/  public/  views/
    app.js.map  bin/    definitions/  package.json   routes/

git push --set-upstream origin master
    Username for 'https://github.com': lhk
    Password for 'https://lhk@github.com': 
    Counting objects: 1486, done.
    Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
    Compressing objects: 100% (1342/1342), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (1486/1486), 3.71 MiB | 561.00 KiB/s, done.
    Total 1486 (delta 306), reused 2 (delta 0)
    remote: warning: File data/krauterkontor.0 is 64.00 MB; this is larger than  
    Github's recommended maximum file size of 50 MB
    remote: warning: File data/local.0 is 64.00 MB; this is larger than GitHub's     
    recommended maximum file size of 50 MB
    remote: error: GH001: Large files detected.
    remote: error: Trace: 3082472065ce69786a2ff7d409d1cb92
    remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
    remote: error: File data/journal/j._0 is 1024.00 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size 
    limit of 100 MB
    remote: error: File data/journal/prealloc.1 is 1024.00 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file 
    size limit of 100 MB
    To https://github.com/lhk/krauterkontor
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/lhk/******'
```

What is going on there ? First it doesn't add data/, then it tries to push it.

```
git rm -r data/
    fatal: pathspec 'data/' did not match any files
```

**UPDATE**:

I really didn't know how to solve this, since it was the first commit to an empty repository, I chose an ugly solution. I just renamed the folder, cloned the repo again, copied all the code to the new folder, added a correct .gitignore and pushed the commit. This worked fine.

Unfortunately I can no longer reproduce the issue, the question is no longer valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.gitignore` must include `data/`, not `data`:

- `data` would ignore any *file* called `data`,
- `data/` would ignore the content of the *folder* `data`.

Comment: thanks, i changed this error, but strangely the push still fails

Comment: I will accept your answer, since the updated gitignore worked in a clean repository. I really don't know what went wrong for me. And a this point, it's no longer reproducable.

Comment: @lhk maybe there was a previous commit (not yet pushed) with `data/` content in it?

Comment: @lhk yes, it could explain why the push kept complaining about a large commit to push, even after you ignored `data/`.